# Possible to set 2 data fields within 1 select option?

Tags: form

I have the following code in my form, but I'd like to also save the eventDate of the selected entry into a separate date field to enable sorting/selection later.

```
<label for="eventName">Event
<select id="eventName" name="fields[eventName]">  
  <option value="">select from list</option>
    {% set events = craft.entries.find({section:'events,activities', eventDate : ">= " ~ now.w3cDate() , order:'eventDate'}) %}
    {% if events %}
        {% for entry in events %}                
            <option value="{{ entry.eventDate.format('D j M') }},{{ entry.eventName }}">{{ entry.eventDate.format('D j M') }},{{ entry.eventName }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</select>            
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no simple answer that didn't require another plugin or javascript I revised my entry form to collect the date manually. Which is a bit of a pain, as the input format for the date has to be mm/dd/yyyy, which isn't normal in the UK.

Comment: Don't picture the Preparse plugin as "yet another plugin". It's a tool that actually should be part of every Craft install, so useful.

Comment: I'm coming from ExpressionEngine, and have been bitten by addons that are no longer supported and not updated, and so now I can't update the EE version. I don't want that to happen again. Part of Craft's attraction is that almost everything I want is part of the core so updating isn't a problem.

Comment: Have a look at all the maintainers: https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft/commits/master. Brandon is a one of them and he's a big fan of that plugin. It's here to stay, even if Andre should remove it from GitHub, I bet there will be a replacement plugin within a few days.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Preparse plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) to create a field that is automatically updated with the `eventDate` value whenever the entry is saved. It wouldn't be a datetime field, but if you stored the *timestamp* (i.e. `{{ dateString|date('U') }}`) it'd be easy to *use* as such.

Another option is to have an hidden input in your form for the `eventDate` datetime field, and use JavaScript to set its value whenever the `<select>` input changes (i.e. listen for the `change` event for the latter, in your JS).

The third option would be to write a plugin which listens to the `entries.beforeSaveEntry` event in order to set the `eventDate` value from the dropdown field.

Comment: Auto Expire plugin allows to copy to a Date/Time field.